# i18next Single translation String Fallback / Default (Vue JS)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internationalization, i18next

Been using`i18next` then I've tried to make for some translated string I fallback value that will be in another language, per example:

```
en:
  base.json
    "yes":"yes"
    "no": "no"

fr:
  base.json
    "yes": "oui"
     "no: ""
```

So the expected behavior that I want is when the vue is running on `FR` and I try to do `{{ i18n.t('base:no' }}` the output should be `no` rather than an empty string.

Here is what I tried so far:

Initialisation:

```
i18next
    .use(languageDetector)
    .init({
      fallbackLng: 'en',
      load: 'languageOnly',
      detection: {
        order: ['querystring', 'navigator']
      }
    })
```

And when outputting: `{{ i18n.t('base:no', {lng: 'en'} }}` I just get an empty string.

Also tried to load the fallback language as well on init, but doesn't work

Anyone stumbled upon this before?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry now i see...you got an empty string as translation of "no" in french...empty string per default is a valid translation.

You can set `returnEmptyString: false` on init to not allow empty string as valid value for translation: https://www.i18next.com/configuration-options.html#translation-defaults

Comment: it's a shame that the i18next docs don't mention the need for that config setting  here :  https://www.i18next.com/principles/fallback#key-fallback

Answer (score 0):

from your init it seems you neither pass in translations nor load them: https://www.i18next.com/add-or-load-translations.html

Do you get any result for `console.log(i18next.services.resourceStore.data);`

Comment: the translations work correctly, just didn't post the snipet where I load languages because we used some loops and its pointless to post it here

Comment: set debug: true on init...seems more like a timing issue calling i18n.t before init callback called (async loading of translations). FallbackLng should be loaded...enough tests on the project asserting that.